# How to achieve route shallow nesting like ROR in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, routes, crud

I want to apply such a concept in Laravel:

> **Shallow nesting**
>
> Adding the ‘shallow: true’ parameter to your nested resource will
>   define routes at the base level, ‘/songs/’, for four of our RESTful
>   routes — show, edit, update and destroy, while leaving the remaining
>   routes — index, new, create— at the nested level. So how is this
>   useful to us?
>
> In my model, with artists and songs, we are now able to use the routes
>   starting with ‘/songs/:id’ to view or modify existing songs on an
>   individual basis. Recall that songs belong to artists, so upon
>   creation, we still need to initialize a song with an artist
>   relationship. However, once a song is created, it doesn’t matter to
>   artist relationship if we would like to edit or delete it. And so, we
>   don’t need to follow a lengthy route, such as
>   ‘/artists/:artist_id/songs/:id/edit’ to make our changes.

**Source:** https://medium.com/@jaredrayjohnson1/4-things-i-learned-toying-around-with-nested-resources-in-rails-fed6d761e924

Comment: It's not in the latest docs, but a quick Google search shows that [nested resource routes exist in v5.1](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#restful-nested-resources). Try that, and see if it's still supported.

Comment: My concern is not nesting my concern is built-in support of shallow nesting just like ROR.